# How do I determine whether a path is a local file or not

Tags: java, android

Given just a location as a string, is there a reliable way to determine if this is a local file (such as /mnt/sdcard/test.jpg) or a remote resource (such as http://www.xyz.com/test.jpg)?

Converting it to a Uri with Uri.parse doesn't seem to give me anything to indicate where the file is.

I don't really want to have to look for // in the string!

Comment: checking for www, http or .com?

Comment: String str="local file" or "remote file" then if((str.indexOf("http")||str.indexOf("www"))==-1){//local file}else{//remote file},I thought it may help you

Comment: @Gens & @riser - there are a few other combinations that would also have to be included. If neither the protocol is http (https for example) nor the subdomain was www, this would not work. Whilst I was hoping for a core method that does this for me I think I might have to go for a regex solution such as @Penkov Vladimir proposes below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

uri  format is

```
<protocol>://<server:port>/<path>
```

local files have:

```
file:///mnt/...
```

or just

```
 /mnt
```

so if string  starts with

```
\w+?://
```

and this is not file:// then this is url

Comment: What about `android.resource://`?

Answer (score 24):

You can also check with the [`android.webkit.URLUtil`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/webkit/URLUtil) class

```
URLUtil.isFileUrl(file) || URLUtil.isContentUrl(file)
```

or any other member function of the aforementioned class. **Preceding it with validation is advised**:

```
URLUtil.isValidUrl(file)
```

Comment: This should be accepted, it's the easiest and most elegant way!

Comment: But `URLUtil.isFileUrl("/mnt/sdcard/somefile.txt")` returns `false`.

Comment: not work for this path /storage/emulated/0/Botad News/Images/welcome to botad, the name is enough.png

Comment: static final String FILE_BASE = "file://";
   

   `code` public static boolean isFileUrl(String url) {
        return (null != url) && (url.startsWith(FILE_BASE) &&
                                 !url.startsWith(ASSET_BASE) &&
                                 !url.startsWith(PROXY_BASE));
    }`

Comment: This answer is outdated now that we have the new FileProvider api and local files may exist at a content URI. `isFileUrl()` doesn't check if url starts with `content:`

Answer (score 6):

I also had the same problem and tried to use Penkov Vladimir solution but it didn't work because the Uri had the schema of 'content' which is also not a remote resource.

I used the following code and it worked great.

```
List<Uri> urls = new ArrayList<>();
List<Uri> locals = new ArrayList<>();
for (Uri uri : uris) {
    if (uri.getScheme() != null && (uri.getScheme().equals("content") || uri.getScheme().equals("file"))) {
        locals.add(uri);
    } else {
        urls.add(uri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To avoid hard-coding:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Test {

  public static void main( String args[] ) throws Exception {
    final String[] inputs = {
      "/tmp/file.txt",
      "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
      "file:///~/calendar",
      "mailto:java-net@java.sun.com",
      "urn:isbn:096139210x",
      "gopher://host.com:70/path",
      "wais://host.com:210/path",
      "news:newsgroup",
      "nntp://host.com:119/newsgroup",
      "finger://user@host.com/",
      "ftp://user:password@host.com:2121/",
      "telnet://user:password@host.com",
      "//localhost/index.html"
    };


    for( final String input : inputs ) {
      System.out.println( "---------------------------------------------" );

      final String protocol = getProtocol( input );
      System.out.println( "protocol: " + protocol );

      if( "file".equalsIgnoreCase( protocol ) ) {
        System.out.println( "file    : " + input );
      }
      else {
        System.out.println( "not file: " + input );
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Returns the protocol for a given URI or filename.
   *
   * @param source Determine the protocol for this URI or filename.
   *
   * @return The protocol for the given source.
   */
  private static String getProtocol( final String source ) {
    assert source != null;

    String protocol = null;

    try {
      final URI uri = new URI( source );

      if( uri.isAbsolute() ) {
        protocol = uri.getScheme();
      }
      else {
        final URL url = new URL( source );
        protocol = url.getProtocol();
      }
    } catch( final Exception e ) {
      // Could be HTTP, HTTPS?
      if( source.startsWith( "//" ) ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Relative context: " + source );
      }
      else {
        final File file = new File( source );
        protocol = getProtocol( file );
      }
    }

    return protocol;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the protocol for a given file.
   *
   * @param file Determine the protocol for this file.
   *
   * @return The protocol for the given file.
   */
  private static String getProtocol( final File file ) {
    String result;

    try {
      result = file.toURI().toURL().getProtocol();
    } catch( Exception e ) {
      result = "unknown";
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------
protocol: file
file    : /tmp/file.txt
---------------------------------------------
protocol: http
not file: http://www.stackoverflow.com
---------------------------------------------
protocol: file
file    : file:///~/calendar
---------------------------------------------
protocol: mailto
not file: mailto:java-net@java.sun.com
---------------------------------------------
protocol: urn
not file: urn:isbn:096139210x
---------------------------------------------
protocol: gopher
not file: gopher://host.com:70/path
---------------------------------------------
protocol: wais
not file: wais://host.com:210/path
---------------------------------------------
protocol: news
not file: news:newsgroup
---------------------------------------------
protocol: nntp
not file: nntp://host.com:119/newsgroup
---------------------------------------------
protocol: finger
not file: finger://user@host.com/
---------------------------------------------
protocol: ftp
not file: ftp://user:password@host.com:2121/
---------------------------------------------
protocol: telnet
not file: telnet://user:password@host.com
---------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Relative context: //localhost/index.html
    at Test.getProtocol(Test.java:67)
    at Test.main(Test.java:30)
```

Answer (score 2):

Fo checking if it's a local file you can simply do this:

```
public static boolean isLocalFile(String path) {
        return new File(path).exists();
}
```

To check if it's a url Cameron Ketcham's answer is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [answer by Penkov Vladimir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6575136/1531708), this is the exact Java code I used:

```
String path = "http://example.com/something.pdf";
if (path.matches("(?!file\\b)\\w+?:\\/\\/.*")) {
    // Not a local file
}
```

See it live with [RegExr](http://regexr.com/3dank)

Comment: `/tmp/file.txt` and `file:///~/calendar` [do not validate](http://regexr.com/3f5ah) as files.

Comment: Exactly, because the regex above matches for **remote** files. Maybe we need another regex to actually determine whether a "not-remote file" is a file after all (cf. urn:isbn:096139210x). But if you already now you are dealing with file locations, this regex should do the trick